# SQL Average Number Of Posts Per User Over 6 Months

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

So I have this requirement, this only needs to happen between 2 tables, wall_posts and comments:

1. How many UNIQUE users have posted on their wall in the last six
   months
2. What is the average number of wall posts per user
3. What is theaverage number of comments on a wall post (This will be the JOIN comments table)

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
        DISTINCT user_id,
        COUNT(post_id) as pc
FROM diaries_posts
WHERE post_date < DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -6 MONTH )
GROUP BY user_id
```

Out of which I'm pretty sure the average part (2nd part) is wrong, since I'm not getting AVG_NO_OF_POST per DISTINCT_USER but TOTAL_NO_OF_POSTS per DISTINCT_USER. Any Ideas?

Also I'm wondering if the 3rd part will be a repetative value for the whole table or is there something in this requirement that I'm missing. The average number of replies to a wall post will be a single value, isn't it?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
select user_id, AVG(post_id) as pc
from diaries_posts
where post_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL - 6 MONTH)
group by user_id
```

Comment: I already tried that, but the values I got can't be right: 

user_id 0 avg_posts 15239.0000, 
user_id 66 avg_posts 740.0000, 
user_id 73 avg_posts 2923.8000??

Comment: This is average number of posts per user that we are selecting?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT user_id) as NumUsers,
       count(*) / COUNT(distinct post_id) as AvgPostsPerUsers
FROM diaries_posts dp
WHERE post_date < DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -6 MONTH );
```

This gives the first two answers.  Your question doesn't explain where `comments` come from, so I'm ignoring the third part.